# Using an External Dependency in a Library

Tags: go

I am using [wgo](https://github.com/skelterjohn/wgo) for dependency management in Golang (although I think wgo has little to do with this), wgo has a folder structure like this

```
project/
    .gocfg/
        gopaths
        vendor.json
    vendor/
        src/
            github.com_or_whatever/
```

I have a library I coded myself which uses an `nsq-go` type in one of the exported methods:

```
func AddNsqSubscription(
    topic, channel string, 
    handler nsq.Handler, 
    config *nsq.Config) error { }
```

The library is called `messi` and I import the `nsq-go` like so `"messi/vendor/src/github.com/bitly/go-nsq"`

The problem comes when I try to use this library in another project. For instance, in a project called `scribe` I have the following code (notice the imports):

```
import (
    "scribe/vendor/src/github.com/bitly/go-nsq"
    "scribe/vendor/src/messi"
)

//...
nsqHandler := nsq.HandlerFunc(func(message *nsq.Message) error {
    msgHandler(MessiMessage{message})
    return nil
})

return messi.AddNsqSubscription(destination, subdestination, nsqHandler, nsq.NewConfig())
```

When I `go build` the following error is returned:

> **cannot use** nsqHandler (type "**scribe**/vendor/src/github.com/bitly/go-nsq".HandlerFunc) as type "**messi**/vendor/src/github.com/bitly/go-nsq".Handler in argument to messi.AddNsqSubscription: 
>       "scribe/vendor/src/github.com/bitly/go-nsq".HandlerFunc does not implement "messi/vendor/src/github.com/bitly/go-nsq".Handler (wrong type for HandleMessage method)
>
> **have** HandleMessage(*"**scribe**/vendor/src/github.com/bitly/go-nsq".Message) error
>
>           **want** HandleMessage(*"**messi**/vendor/src/github.com/bitly/go-nsq".Message) error

**Why?** I do not really know what is going on. The code `go-nsq` imported is exactly the same, yet golang wants that this code comes from the same folder?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: AFAIK the best practice is considered not vendoring deps in libraries but only in applications, to avoid these situations. This is what I personally do.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer how should I manage the `go-nsq` dependency in the library?

Comment: just import the paths as-is (github.com/foo/bar), and let the application author vendor all the deps the way they want - with or without path rewriting for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages in Go are identified by full import path, not by name.

For example in the standard library there are two different packages with the same name `template` but different import paths: `text/template` and `html/template`.

You should make sure that `go-nsq` package is imported using the same path.

Comment: You should not vendor dependencies in your `messi` library. Vendor them in the project that uses the library.