# Go lint complains the import when using dep

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, golint

I saw the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969088/using-an-external-dependency-in-a-library). But I couldn't solve my case.

I am having project initialised with dep and added the first dependency "Echo". Now folder structure looks like this

```
|--server
|    |--server.go
|--vendor
|--main.go
```

The server.go has the following code

```
package server

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo"
)

// TestController : Test controller
func TestController(c echo.Context) error {
    return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
}
```

and the main.go has

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    "github.com/sfkshan/pos/server"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    e.GET("/", server.TestController)
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

Now vscode shows the warning

> cannot use server.TestController (type
>   func("github.com/sfkshan/pos/vendor/github.com/labstack/echo".Context)
>   error) as type "github.com/labstack/echo".HandlerFunc in argument to
>   e.GET

I am not sure why is this happening? If I delete the vendor folder folder the error vanishes. But again after running `dep ensure` (in this case vendor folder gets created which is expected) the error appears again.

Comment: Did you already try to delete the folder in your GOPATH? It looks like Go gets mixed up on which package to use

Comment: @JonathanR I am not entirely sure. My $GOPATH is `/Users/hey/Code/go` but I had placed it in my profile like this `/Users/shanmugharajk/Code/Go`. Case was wrong gave `Go` instead of `go`. I changed this in my bash profile and deleted all the packages outside of vendor folder. After that it works fine. But I try to reproduce the issue by repeating the same it doesn't occur. Finally I couldn't figure the reason for the error and how it got resolved :(

Comment: I believe on mac the GOPATH is case sensitive, I had this problem once, too.